# Presigned Download and view in object

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, typescript, pdf, pre-signed-url

Alright i had this working on a public bucket with s3 that i called directly using sdk. When i switched over to presigned it stopped working it looks like presigned sends the pdf differently.

this is the object i want to see the pdf in.

```
<object id="first" data="" type="application/pdf" style="min-height: 585px; min-width:500px; width: 100%; height: 100%">

        <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
          you can <a [href]="firstUrl">click here to
            download the PDF file.</a></p>


      </object>
```

in my ngOnInit i call a function called getPdfs();

```
let storedFiles;

      this.preSign.getList(this.org, this.id)
        .subscribe( result => {
          storedFiles = result;

          let first = this.getPdfFromList(this.form + '.pdf', storedFiles);

          this.preSign.downloadFile(first.url)
            .subscribe( resultt => {
              this.displayPdf(resultt._body, '#first');
            });

        });
```

then displayPdf

```
displayPdf(file, part){
      $(part).attr('data', URL.createObjectURL(new Blob( [ file ], { type: 'application/pdf' } )));
    }
```

I can download and save the pdf correctly i just can not view it in the object. Inside the object the pdf will display very incorrectly. either just showing grey boxes or completely blank.

Before when i was using public bucket this is what i used.

```
$('#first').attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(new Blob( [ new Uint8Array( result.data.Body ) ], { type: 'application/pdf' } )));
```

when i try to use Uint8Array on the presigned one it will say "Can not display PDF" then a reload button is there.